# PostgreSQL SQL: Find single arbitrary tuple from each id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table:

```
 id | x  |  y  
----+----+-----
  1 | 10 | 100
  1 | 20 | 120
  1 | 30 | 130
  2 | 10 | 130
  2 | 20 | 130
  2 | 30 | 130
  3 | 20 | 130
(7 rows)
```

I would like to have a single arbitrary tuple of every `id`, with the corresponding `x` and `y` values. The following results are correct:

```
 id | x  |  y  
----+----+-----
  1 | 10 | 100
  2 | 20 | 130
  3 | 20 | 130
```

Or:

```
 id | x  |  y  
----+----+-----
  1 | 30 | 130
  2 | 30 | 130
  3 | 20 | 130
```

Neither `id`, `x` nor `y` are unique in any context.

How do I go about this in SQL (under `PostgreSQL`)? There might be some millions of `id`s.

**Update:**

Thanks, @Lukáš Lalinský. Quoting the PostgreSQL documentation you've linked to:

> `DISTINCT ON` ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each
>   set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal... Note that the "first row" of each set is
>   unpredictable unless `ORDER BY` is used to ensure that the desired row
>   appears first.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: More, I don't understand what you're expecting and how you came to your examples.  Your base table already seems to be a unique set.  Are you just trying to randomly pick one record per ID?

Comment: I would like to get a single **arbitrary** row for each `id`. That is, one row with id=1, one with id=2 and one with id=3. I don't care which row within the same id set is chosen.

Comment: Adam Matan, that makes sense, I'm curious why anyone would ever want that, though.

Comment: @vol7ron: I have occasion to need this sort of thing all the time.  An application 'assumes' that two things are one-to-one, but the schema indicates otherwise.  There's nothing in the spec for the application that indicates which of the many values should be preferred.

Comment: Token, this would only give you a random selection of data.  Sure it's not entirely random data, but of the data exists, you're getting a random unique set.  I don't get why someone would want that, other than to display a quick example.

Comment: @vol7ron suppose you want to run a simulation on users transactions, and you need a single transaction per user. You don't really care which transaction to take, as long as all your users are represented.

Comment: @Adam: so for testing?  it seems like i've only needed to do this one time and I can't for the life of me remember why

Comment: @vol7ron not only testing; This is useful any time you need a single sample from each category. This can happen with simulations that need real data or GIS samples for viewing on maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) clause should do the job:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, x, y FROM table
```